# A formula to do performance measure

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two column of records

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3

100      |   1      |        
110      |   2      |
130      |   4      |
```

---

I will calculate the corresponding values for column 3

column 3 = (column 2/ column 1) * 100

What will be formula I should use to calculate values for column 3 ... I'm very new to Excel ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be trying to achieve a percentage. If that is true, I would advise you to stick with the straight ratio of B1/A1. If not, no need to read further.

```
=B1/A1
```

Format the cells in column C as a percentage to get it looking like 50% and adjust the decimal points if you wish. If you multiply by 100 then you get an integer that looks like 50 but is not 50%. The underlying value of 50% is 0.5 and it should be kept that way to use in future calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The following should go into the first row, then pasted into the other cells

```
=($B1 / $A1) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If column 1 is A then

```
=(B1/A1)*100
```

[image]